# Shortcut to see result of a Query in VS-Code itself rather than keep checking in Developer Console?

Tags: apex, soql, vs-code

I wanted to know if there is any shortcut, with which we can instantly check result of SOQL query written in Apex class in VS-code itself rather than every time keep checking it in Developer Console??

Answer (score 3):

You can execute the query written on the Apex class by following the below step:

[image]

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quickstart-vscode-salesforce/use-vscode-for-salesforce

Answer (score 0):

You can execute SOQL query right inside your VS Code now. Salesforce introduced this cool feature. I have written a blog post regarding this one, which you can check out @ https://www.sudipta-deb.in/2020/11/soql-query-builder-vscode.html

Video : https://youtu.be/LG13jPWYqVw